# formdata via ajax with groovy

Tags: javascript, ajax, groovy, form-data

I'm trying to transfer an  image-file and corresponding information via ajax to a groovlet-server.

Problem:
I can't get the data out of the HTTPServletRequest obect.

Here is the Javascript-Code that I use to transfer the data:

```
$("#submitButton").click( function(){
        if ( submitButtonCondition == true ) {

            //Gathering Data                
            var enabledValue = false;
            if ($("#activate").val()){
                enabledValue = true;
            }       
            var metadata = $("#metaTextarea").val();                                
            var inputFile = $("#fileInput")[0].files[0];

            // Creating FormData-Object filled with necessary Data
            var formData = new FormData();      
            formData.append('file', inputFile);
            formData.append('enabled', enabledValue);
            formData.append('metadata', metadata);

            // Sending FormData to Server
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : '/createNewEntry.groovy',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function(resultData){  
                    console.log("Upload successful");
                },
                failure: function(resultData){
                    console.log("Upload failed");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The only way of verifying if data has been send has been accessing the attached reader of the request object: `System.out.println(request.reader.text);`

Output looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryzNUfRksUAVW2ioCa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blatest.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryzNUfRksUAVW2ioCa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="enabled"

true
------WebKitFormBoundaryzNUfRksUAVW2ioCa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"

asdfasdfasdf
------WebKitFormBoundaryzNUfRksUAVW2ioCa--
```

So apparently the data has been transferred?
Still, I'm struggling to get information out of methods `getParameter, getParameterMap, getParameterNames, getParameterValues` which all give me no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the Parts using the following external libraries:

`org.apache.commons.fileupload`
`org.apache.commons.io`

Code then looks like this:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    // Figure out ServerContext
    ServletContext servletContext = context;

    // Configure a repository (to ensure a secure temp location is used)
    File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");

    // Set factory constraints
    factory.setSizeThreshold(50000);
    factory.setRepository(repository);

    // Create a new file upload handler
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    // Parse the request
    List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

    // Process the uploaded items
    Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        FileItem item = iter.next()
        if (item.isFormField()) {
            processFormField(item);

        } else {
            processUploadedFile(item, servletContext);
        }
    }
```

`request` and `response` are related to the groovlet object.

The methods `processFormField()` and `ProcessUploadedFile()` can access the form-Data and cached Files.

`processFormField()` for example is accessing the information the following way:

```
    private void processFormField(FileItem item) {
    String name = item.getFieldName()
    String value = item.getString()
    if (name=="enabled") {
        queryEnabledValue=value;
    }
    if (name=="metadata") {
        queryMetadata=value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you got on server side multipart request

normally your `request` should be instanceof

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

and you can use methods:

- `Part getPart(java.lang.String name)` Gets the Part with the given name.
- `java.util.Collection<Part> getParts()`

Comment: Unfortunately the getPart-Methods did not work as well.


`System.out.println(request.getPart("file"));`
`System.out.println(request.getPart("enabled"));`
`System.out.println(request.getPart("metadata"));`
`System.out.println(request.getParts().size());`
 
Output:
`null`
`null`
`null`
`0`

Comment: check in browser DevTools what content type sent to server. because you are submitting several input types and one of them `file` - you must have `content-type: multipart/...`. then servlet should parse it as multipart.

Comment: `Request Headers` `content-type: multipart/form-data` corresponding to Chrome Dev-Tools's network log.

Comment: Still, unfortunately the collection of request.getParts() has length 0.         
Btw thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: what class for your servlet? `groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet`?

Comment: I'm running the Groovy-Script on a Tomcat 9. Corresponding to the web.xml, groovy files are proccessed with `groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet`

Comment: what is the output of `println request.getClass()` ? groovy version?

Comment: `class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade`     Groovy-Version: `2.4.12`